# how to save face in separate file every time of code running that is taken using opencv-python

Tags: python

i want to write the face of one person in one folder at first opencv-pyhon code running after that when i run that code second times the face of person is save/write in another folder without changing . it also may be put that image by increasing the folder number.
Please post a line of code for this..please immediately . you can describe in in your own..

Comment: it's not clear what exact action you are trying to achieve. please describe the situation more clearly, with code.

Comment: i am trying to save one person face into one folder when we execute the opencv-python code first time . Then when i open the code second time for getting second person face then i want to save second person face into another separate folder automatically without manually change the code second time and the path to save these two person face is also same. Is this clear now?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name of the folder using system argument or argument parser. Click this link to see details about [argument parser](http://You%20can%20pass%20the%20name%20of%20the%20folder%20using%20system%20argument%20or%20argument%20parser.%20Or%20use%20a%20unique%20folder%20name%20every%20time%20the%20code%20runs.%20One%20way%20of%20achieving%20this%20using%20UUID.). Or you can let the code generate a unique folder name every time the code runs. One way of achieving this using UUID. To know about UUID click this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html).

Comment: your first link didn't open